# Integration with trigonometric substitution

Tags: integration

Hey I need help With this exercise:

We have to substitute $x = \tan(\delta/2)$,   and then we know that $\sin(\delta) = 2x/(1+x^2)$
and $\cos(\delta) = (1-x^2)/(1+x^2)$.

Then we have to compute this integral: 
$$\int \frac{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)(x^2+9)}\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Just use the partial descomposition
$$
\begin{align} \int \frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}dx
&= \int \left(\frac{1}{4(x^2+1)}-\frac{5}{4(x^2+9)}\right)dx \\
&= \frac14 \arctan(x)-\frac54 \int \frac{1}{x^2+9}dx \\
&= \frac14 \arctan(x)-\frac54 \cdot \frac13 \arctan\Big(\frac{x}{3}\Big)+c
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Though it is right, but the question is that you need to do this question by substituting $x=\tan(\dfrac{\delta}{2})$

Comment: That substitution is employed in rational functions of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. What I really understand is that integral that appears in your question is the result of applying that substitution.